# cuda-gdb Error message

Tags: cuda, cuda-gdb

I tried to debug my CUDA application with cuda-gdb but got some weird error.

I set option `-g -G -O0` to build my application. I could run my program without cuda-gdb, but didn't get correct result. Hence I decided to use cuda-gdb, however, I got following error message while running program with cuda-gdb

`Error: Failed to read the valid warps mask (dev=1, sm=0, error=16).`

What does it means? Why `sm=0` and what's the meaning of `error=16`?

**Update 1**: I tried to use cuda-gdb to CUDA samples, but it fails with same problem. I just installed CUDA 6.0 Toolkit followed by instruction of NVIDIA. Is it a problem of my system?

**Update 2**:

- OS - CentOS 6.5
- GPU

  - 1 Quadro 400
  - 2 Tesla C2070
  - I'm using only 1 GPU for my program, but I've got same bug message from any GPU that I selected
- CUDA version - 6.0
- GPU Driver

  - NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  331.62  Wed Mar 19 18:20:03 PDT 2014
  - GCC version:  gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)

**Update 3**:
I tried to get more information in cuda-gdb, but I got following results

`(cuda-gdb) info cuda devices
Error: Failed to read the valid warps mask (dev=1, sm=0, error=16).
(cuda-gdb) info cuda sms
Focus not set on any active CUDA kernel.
(cuda-gdb) info cuda lanes
Focus not set on any active CUDA kernel.
(cuda-gdb) info cuda kernels
No CUDA kernels.
(cuda-gdb) info cuda contexts
No CUDA contexts.`

Comment: You might want to file an nvidia bug report.  This is [the link to do it](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvbugs/cuda/add), however you'll need to be [logged in as a registered developer](http://developer.nvidia.com) first.  The best scenario would be if you can provide a short program that reproduces the problem, and also provide your exact machine configuration (OS, CUDA version, GPU, GPU driver, etc.) plus whatever cuda-gdb commands are needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Updated detail. I can run sample application from NVIDIA, but `cuda-gdb` doesn't work neither, which means running program without debugger is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this issue is only specific to some old NVIDIA GPUs(like "Quadro 400", "GeForce GT220", or "GeForce GT 330M", etc).

On Liam Kim's setup, cuda-gdb should work fine by set environment variable "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", and let cuda-gdb running on Tesla C2070 GPUs specifically.
I.e
$export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 (or 2) 
- the exact CUDA devices index could be found by running cuda sample - "deviceQuery".

And now, this issue has been fixed, the fix would be availble for CUDA developers in the next CUDA release(it will be posted out around early July, 2014).

Comment: The CUDA6.5 Release Candidate (RC) is now available to all CUDA Registered Developers. It should contain this fix.
Learn more at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit

Comment: I'm using CUDA6.5 and still having this problem. I have a GeForce GTX 860M. If I set a breakpoint in my cuda code, after it is triggered a few times I get "Error: Failed to read the valid warps mask (dev=0, sm=3, error=16)." I have set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0.

Answer (score 2):

This is internal `cuda-gdb` bug. You should report a bug.

Can you try installing CUDA toolkit from the package on NVIDIA site?

Comment: Yes, I installed from a repo provided by NVIDIA site.

Comment: I confirmed it was a bug from NVIDIA. They said they are working on fix now.